# Is this unsafe way to use malloc?

Tags: c, security

If the x and y parameter receive data from untrusted user would this piece of code pose some security threat?

```
char *p = malloc(x * y); 
while (x > 0) 
  while (y > 0) 
    *p++ = 0;
```

**Update:**

Most people seems to comment on that it is an infinite loop and that this code piece will crash the program eventually when it write over its allocated memory.
**However** except for that problem. Isn't there possibly some issue with how malloc is used? E.g. heap overflow since no upper bound check for x and y?

Comment: One problem here is that the code leaks memory. When it's finished executing you can't pass `p` into `free`, and the original value has been lost.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these loops?

Comment: Yes, it is unsafe. You need to check the return value from `malloc`.

Comment: This piece of code is not security itself for x and y never changes.

Comment: Maybe you forget to type some code like --x, --y?

Comment: Another, more subtle problem is that `x * y` might overflow, in which case you'll likely allocate less than you intend.

Comment: Actually this is from a previous exam question. I've discussed with some classmates and couldn't come to some answer. Since we all see it will become an infinitely loop and seg fault at the end. REGARDLESS of who the user is.

Answer (score 6):

You will write memory infinitely until the program craps out if x and y are positive, which I would expect.  Not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Receiving that code from a TRUSTED user would be a problem.

`x` and `y` never change. Assuming one of them is positive, the while loops will always evaluate to the same thing, and result in an infinite loop. If both are positive, you will keep writing memory until your program crashes.

Not a good piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

If `y` and `x` are greater than `0`, this will cause undefined behavior since you enter an infinite loop and assigning `0` to a pointer that points to memory you don't own.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will write into memory that's not allocated, and the program will segfault.

Use memset if you want to empty a block of memory, the prototype looks like this:

```
void * memset(void *dest, int c, size_t count);
```

so the code would look something like this:

```
char *p = malloc(x * y);
memset(p, 0, x * y);
```

Comment: Every time I see `malloc` and `memset` combined, I want to tear my hair of. Use `calloc`!

Comment: good point, and it would also be a good thing to check the return from malloc/calloc before trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a security threat. Either you get values larger than 0, which will put you in an infinite loop and overwrite your process' memory until a segmentation fault occurs and your process dies. If one of the parameters is zero, you have a call to `malloc(0)`, which might result in a memory leak.

The code is completely mad anyway, so I asume your question was academic.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the code you've posted contains an infinite loop. You probably meant to do the following:

```
char *p = malloc( sizeof(x) * x * y ); 

if( p != NULL ) {
  memset( p, 0, sizeof(x) * x * y );
} else {
  // error allocating memory, handle it somehow
}
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying by `sizeof(x) * sizeof(y)`? If either size is greater than 1 then that will write over more memory than was allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,there is an infinite loop and there can be a stack overflow, in your while loops.
Also Not sure how it is going to pose security threat, but it is a potential threat to the system, as it can cause memory issues.
There is no check of boundaries for "x" and "y", so user can send in a huge amount of data and you might get segmentation fault error.
There is missing cast of address returned by the malloc.
Also the coding style(*p++) confuses people so, it is difficult to maintain such a code.
This code will surely fail the application in real world.